# Oracle ODP.NET BulkCopy to temporary table issue

Tags: oracle, odp.net, sqlbulkcopy, ora-03113

I'm using BulkCopy method from ODP.NET to insert a DataTable to a temporary table.
If the temporary table is simple (no triggers or indexes) it works, fine, but as soon as I create an index or trigger, i get the "End-of-file on communication channel" error at BulkCopy.WriteToServer() method.
Any idea how could i fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of an ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel, the server process dedicated to your session died because of a bug or error. The client process detects that the server process is missing and raises the ORA-03113. The server process has written its error message to the alert file. Check this file on the server to find out what went wrong. You may have to ask your DBA to do this for you.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: ORA-03113 and ORA-00600's are all errors that you can't really put a finger on and say, 'do this and you'll fix it'. The advice for those is, 'you have to really dig cuz this is likely a bug in Oracle'.

Comment: The times when I have hit an ORA-03113, the real error message was waiting for me in the alert file. Of course, upon discovering the real message, the fix might be hard or even impossible, but "really dig" is worded too strong in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the posters above. Check your alert log file. If you see an ORA-600 there, you (or your DBA) should contact Oracle support because you may need a patch.

Christian Shay
Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Temporary tables in Oracle are almost always a bad idea.  Can you re-design the program to use either a regular table or a PL/SQL collection?

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted Oracle about this. Apparently it's a bug, that was fixed in 11g. They're now trying to release a patch